# In JavaFX how to access control with in a perticular row in TreeTableView

Tags: javafx

I have a TreeTableView with couple of columns. One of the column is having ProgressIndicator, which is generated using setCellFactory on TreeTableColumn. This table contains list of files.

User selects a row and click on download button then I am getting selected row by calling getSelectionModel() but the problem is I am getting the value of the row (data) but how I can get the progressIndicator which I injected in the column. So while file download I can update this indicator.

Below is the code:

```
//Table setup with two columns; file name and progressindicator column, File is my custom class which contains file related info.
@FXML TreeTableView<File> table = new TreeTableView<>();
@FXML TreeTableColumn<File, String> fileCol = new TreeTableColumn<>();
@FXML TreeTableColumn<File, String> progressCol = new TreeTableColumn<>();

//Generating progress indicator with setCellFactory
progressCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
        @Override public TreeTableCell<File, String> call(TreeTableColumn<File, String> p) {
            return new TreeTableCell<>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                            ProgressIndicator p1 = new ProgressIndicator();
                            p1.setMaxWidth(20);
                            p1.setMaxHeight(20);
                            setGraphic(p1);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });

//I have a download button, when it is click below code is executed
download.setOnAction(event -> {
        //Here I am getting File object but I also need to get progressindicator which is in progressCol, how I can get it?
        File object = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue();
    });
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve] that demonstrates what you've done so far.

Comment: please check the code. I just updated.

Comment: Why you are not creating your own `MyCustomTreeTableColumn extends TreeTableColumn`and there declare some functions and the `ProgressIndicator`

Comment: @Raw extending a _column_ wouldn't help if you need _cell_ related functionality - so no, that's not an option (if I understand the OP correctly ;) A custom cell implementation is the way to go, with an appropriate property of the data that reflects the progress

Comment: @kleopatra Sorry I meant cell, but I have referred to the column. :)

Answer (score -1):

Just create a wrapper class for the File and the ProgressIndicator, and use that for the TreeTableView.

```
public class FileWrapper {  
  private File file;
  private ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();

  public FileWrapper(File file) {
    this.file = file;
  }

  public File getFile() {
    return file;
  }

  public ProgressIndicator getProgressIndicator() {
    return progressIndicator;
  }

}
```

When using DataTables in JavaFx the "type" of the DataTable should represent one row, in your case the File only covers one column.
So your code would look something like this:

```
@FXML
private TreeTableView<FileWrapper> tableView;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<FileWrapper, String> fileCol;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<FileWrapper, ProgressIndicator> progressCol;

@FXML
public void initialize() throws IOException {
    fileCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getValue().getFile().getName()));
    progressCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue().getValue().getProgressIndicator()));
    progressCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TreeTableCell<>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(ProgressIndicator item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(null);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setGraphic(item);
            }
        }
    });
```

And at the download action:

```
download.setOnAction(event -> {
    File object = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue().getFile();
    ProgressIndicator = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue().getProgressIndicator()
});
```

Comment: no - never-ever put nodes into your data. Instead, let it keep track of the progress and use that data item to drive an appropriate control in a custom cell